# Point count within borders, in two different layers, using QGIS

Tags: qgis

I have a layer of georeferenced points, and a layer of vectorized borders. Is there a way I can use QGIS to calculate how many points fall within each area of the borders layer?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There is a tool under vector > analysis tools > points in polygon that does the job.

[image]

You get a new window where you can define the layers

[image]

In the new shapefile there will be a new column with the counts.